# pug nested content in input

Tags: node.js, pug

Hi I'm trying to create nested mixins which can display [bootstrap radio button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons) in pug

```
mixin input(textinput)
   label.btn.btn-secondary
      input(type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off")= textinput

mixin btn-toggle-group(textinput)
   .btn-group(data-toggle="button")

    +btn-toggle-group  
                    +input('coca')
                    +input('pepsi')
                    +input('orangina')
                    +input('lemonade')
```

but it gives me error with input is a self closing element but it contains nested content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to trying to make `textinput` a `TextNode` child of a radio button via `=` which obviously has to fail.

If one wants to render a ***next sibling*** text node, there is the `|` operator (pipe) and interpolation. But one also can go with just another html element like `span`. Bothe variants are provided with the example code.

One should keep in mind that a radio button (especially within a radio group) that does not feature a value is of almost no use. It might be useful, assigning `textinput` to the radio button's `value` attribute too.

One also should avoid passing `id` or `class` attributes directly into a ***tag***, one instead should append each of it either by `#` for ids or by `.` for class names.

And last, for one wants to append all the labeled radio controls to the `btn-group` classified `div` element, one needs to mark this by a carefully indented `block` keyword.

```
mixin input(textinput)
    label.btn.btn-secondary
        input#option1(type='radio' name='options' autocomplete='off' value=textinput)
        // span.label= textinput
        // span= textinput
        | #{textinput}

mixin btn-toggle-group(textinput)
    .btn-group(data-toggle='button')
        block

+ btn-toggle-group
    + input('coca')
    + input('pepsi')
    + input('orangina')
    + input('lemonade')
```

The above provided sanitized and tested code now does work as intended.

And reading the [pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) ([attributes](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html), [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html), [mixins](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html), [inheritance/templates/blocks](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html), )  does help too.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by 'One needs to assign textinput to the radio button's value attribute.' because in the docs https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html#mixin-blocks title can be use as a TextNode child of article-wrapper. Why in my case I had to add value=textinput

Comment: `textinput` as with your example (*"coca"*, *"pepsi"*, ...) obviously carries the value of a radio button. Your attempt of making it the value of a *next sibling* text node of each radio button did fail since `<input/>` is a self closing element. Thus `=` does not work but `|` does the job. This was the source of the error. But I did not only fix all of your other syntax errors, I also hinted you to assign the value of `textinput` to each of a radio button`s value too. After all, a radio button is of almost no use without a value, especially within a radio group.

Comment: Referring to the OP's comment ... *because in the [docs](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html#mixin-blocks) ... `title` can be use as a TextNode child* ... A mixin can be seen as a render specific function. One is free of naming a mixin's arguments however one likes. Each argument carries data. In order to apply/render this data into the right context one has to be aware of the correct usage of e.g. interpolation/escaping and/or operators like `=` and `|`.